# Angular response headers value

Tags: angular, wordpress-rest-api

I get a request from WP Rest Api in Angular

**service.ts**

```
get(): Observable<any>{
return  this.http.get<any>('mysite.com/posts?categories=4&per_page=2'));
}
```

**app-component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.RestApi.get()
  .subscribe(
    e => {
      console.log(e);
      console.log('headers: ' + e.headers);
    });}
```

response

[DevTools - Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBI7i.png)  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBI7i.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBI7i.png

**DevTools - Console:**

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
    0: {id: 100, date: "2018-02-27T18:38:59", ...}
    1: {id: 98, date: "2018-02-27T18:38:34", ...}
    length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

headers: undefined
```

So, why in Network I see Response Headers, but in Console I have undefined?
How I can get value of 'X-WP-TotalPages'? What I do wrong?

Thx for attention!
I hope for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass `{ observe: 'response' }` option into your `http.get` method so that it can return an Observable of typed `HttpResponse` rather than just the JSON data.

To show each of the headers, you can do something like this

```
this.RestApi.get()
  .subscribe(
    e => {
      console.log(e);
      // debugger; 
      this.headers = e.headers.keys().map(key =>
        console.log(`${key}: ${e.headers.get(key)}`));
    });
}
```

Also you could set a debugger in the code (uncomment the line) so that the browser will break right at the line, and then you can inspect the values as needed.

Comment: Thx! :) 

I did as you said and saw all the keys x-wp-totalpages: 3 content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 x-wp-total: 5 Then I add this.headers = e.headers.get('x-wp-totalpages'); console.log('x-wp-totalpages: ' + this.headers); and hooray!!! i get value of x-wp-totalpages. (sory for text design, I did not find how to break the text into lines, Shift + Enter and <br/> does not help :(... )

Answer (score 1):

`http.get(...)` does not return an object with a `headers` property at all.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

If you use the `observe` option you can get the full response like so:

```
this.http.get<Config>('mysite.com/posts?categories=4&per_page=2', { observe: 'response' });
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response